# Sending email with inline attachments using .NET 4.7.1 and SendGrid SMTP

Tags: c#, .net, email-attachments, smtpclient, .net-4.7.2

Editted: I am using SendGrid SMTP to send out automated emails within my .NET 4.7.1 web application. The emails send fine, except when it comes to the inline attachments (company logo's, etc), the attachments aren't sent with it. I just inherited this project and apparently this worked before using MailGun, but switching to SendGrid SMTP it no longer works.

I have image that is read from disk, only its the wrong image. It's taking an image that I previously had - but deleted completely and searched my HD for - and saving that to the directory I specify in code below. The name is correct, but the actual byte content saved is wrong.

It IS attaching an image - but not displaying it inline even though the file name is the same as the cid: referenced in the <img src""> tag.

This is part of the email body generated that was supposed to reference this inline attachment

```
<img src="cid:Email-Logo-USA.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width: 100%; max-width: 380px;" />
```

This is the class handling all the emailing and attachment sending

```
internal class MailGunEmailService : IEmailService
    {
        private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private readonly string path = "~/App_Data/attachments/";

        public void Send(
            MailAddress from,
            ICollection<MailAddress> to,
            ICollection<MailAddress> cc,
            ICollection<MailAddress> bcc,
            string subject,
            string body,
            ICollection<Attachment> attachments)
        {
            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from.ToString());
            //var request = new RestRequest();

            if (to != null && to.Count > 0)
                foreach (var emailTo in to)
                    message.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(emailTo.ToString()));

            if (cc != null && cc.Count > 0)
                foreach (var carbonCopy in cc)
                    message.CC.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(carbonCopy.ToString()));


            if (bcc != null && bcc.Count > 0)
                foreach (var blindCarbonCopy in bcc)
                    message.Bcc.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(blindCarbonCopy.ToString()));

            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = body;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            // Attachments currently do not work
            // Need to get the path(s) to the file(s) and add to email using System.Net.Mail.Attachments()
            if (attachments != null)
            {
                foreach (var attachment in attachments.Where(a => !a.Inline))
                    message.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachment.FileName));

                foreach (var attachment in attachments.Where(a => a.Inline))
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path)))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path) ?? string.Empty);

                    var attachmentPath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path) ?? string.Empty,
                        attachment.FileName);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(attachmentPath, attachment.Content);

                    var att = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachmentPath);
                    att.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
                    att.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
                    message.Attachments.Add(att);
                }
            }

            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Attachment.FileName` property specifies the filename of the attachment but does not supply the file content itself.

To fix this, you can upload the file content to a [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1#system-io-memorystream-ctor(system-byte())) object and then attach it to the email using the `Attachment.ContentStream` property instead of `Attachment.FileName`.

```
...
if (attachment.Inline)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(attachment.FileName));

    var inlineAttachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, attachment.Name, attachment.ContentType);
    inlineAttachment.ContentId = attachment.ContentId;
    inlineAttachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
    message.Attachments.Add(inlineAttachment);
}
else
{
    message.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachment.FileName));
}
...
```